# Json array deserialize from DataContractJsonSerializer method to JsonConvert(newton.json)?

Tags: c#, json

I need to deserialize json array from web api (httpclient). I have DataContractJsonSerializer but no use i need to use JsonConvert, I don't know how to do this. My code:

```
{
    [DataContract]
    public class JsonDataContractObject
    {
        public string ToJson()
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(this.GetType());
            Stream s = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(s, this);
            s.Position = 0;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

How to change DataContractJsonSerializer to JsonConvert(newton.json)?.

Comment: Why not use a library for integrate the api? RestSharp is a really very good library that will help you with all of the rest integration. This allow you customize calls, serializer and deserializers if you need. This will ver really simple and will get you life easy !!!

Comment: Hi Mauri, Thanks for your info. I never try RestSharp before and already i build my project using this method thats why even very short time.

Comment: yes, I know that this is really simple. But if you need to do integrations with a lot of api, using a library is more simple. Each api need different requirements, authentication, response, etc. I use this tool for almost of my api integrations and is really good. This handle all of the requirements that I need integration more than 12 different api. I recommend to think about this, if you will need more integrations. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks Mauri, Can you share any link about this?

Comment: Sure, here is the github repo: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp the site http://restsharp.org/ and the nugget package on https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/ I m sure that this will help you. Let me know if you have any doubt. As I mentioned I used this for my integrations so I have a lot of experience and examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, Let me try and back to you:)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to quickly serialise an object to json string

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
```

For more info see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: Hi thanks for the update, But i need to deserialize the object. I need to add code like var machine1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Machine1>>(json1);

Comment: That's exactly how you'll do it!